# error on time app: warning: 'UILabel' may not respond to '-setStringValue:'

Tags: xcode, time, uilabel

I write the code below and I get the following error:

```
warning: 'UILabel' may not respond to '-setStringValue:'


@synthesize label; 
- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender { 
NSDate * now = [NSDate date]; NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"]; 
NSString *currentTime = [formatter stringFromDate:now]; 
[label setStringValue:currentTime];
[currentTime writeToFile:@"/Users/Desktop/log.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:NULL]; }
```

and another question: if the time app is on your ipod, can it save the time too ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no UILabel method called `setStringValue:` which is why you get the warning. You are trying to call a selector which isn't implemented. I assume you are trying to set the text of the UILabel, if so, you would use the `setText:` selector like so:

```
[label setText:currentTime];
```

You can find more information about the UILabel Class on Apple's Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html